# Jquery ajax call loads entire current page in div on success

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to load content from a simple external file into a div when a button is clicked using ajax. The text file simply contains a paragraph of text in a

tag. When the button is clicked, the text does not load into the div, instead the entire contents of the current page load into the div.

Here is a section of my code:

```html
<a class="button" id="fav">Add</a>
   
<div id="div1">Div 1: </div>

<script>
jQuery("#fav").click(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "test.txt", 
    success: function(result){
      jQuery("#div1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, examine the AJAX request in the network tab.  Is the requested URL what you expect?  What is the content of the server's response?

Comment: Are you able to call button click using provided code? Additionally, what you are getting into console?

Comment: Check in DevTools console whether you have 404 error for test.txt. If so, put it in actual folder.

Comment: The URL was not what I was expecting. I used an absolute path and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `dataType`.

```
<script>
jQuery("#fav").click(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "test.txt",
    dataType: "html", //html, json, raw etc
    success: function(result){
      jQuery("#div1").html(result);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```